# Localization of CSS resources in Lift 2.5

Tags: css, localization, lift

I'm relatively new to Lift and I'm running into a problem getting localization working for CSS files. I've read this: http://timperrett.com/2009/07/26/how-to-extensive-localization-with-the-liftweb-framework/
as well as this:
http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-D.html
as well as a host of Google results, none of which has helped me.

I *have* been able to get templates (*.html) successfully localized by following Mr. Perret's example, adding localeCalculator() to Boot.scala and etc.... So depending on the current locale, one of these templates is curently used:

```
1. index_en_US.html
2. index_pt_BR.html
3. index_de.html
```

Works great!

My problem is in getting CSS files loaded in the same manner. So even though I have these three files stored:

```
1. myAwesomeCSS.css
2. myAwesomeCSS_pt_BR.css
3. myAwesomeCSS_de.css
```

the only CSS resource loaded is myAwesomeCSS.css (not so awesome)

According to Tim, "This exact same scheme [the one I describe above] also applies for CSS resources." I don't know what I've done wrong, but it seems that if it's working for templates, it should be working for CSS files... Before I go running down the rabbit hole of custom resource bundles, I thought I'd ask to see if I'm missing something obvious - something like remove the css directory from LiftRules.liftRequest - tried that and it din't work :(

Any other suggestions?

Comment: By default, js and css files aren't processed by Lift. Try renaming the extension to `.liftcss` and see if you can access them with the localization that way.

Comment: I tried that. Maven just overwrote the filenames (foo.liftcss becomes foo.liftcss.css). I'll monkey with Maven to see if I can prevent that from happening. I did try placing the files in the ResourceServer directory (classpath) and that didn't work either. Very frustrating.

Comment: Ack. That doesn't work either.... I'm beginning to see I've sort of answered my own question. We currently forward CSS requests to the container via liftRequest. So we can hardly expect to  retain the benefits of the Lift pipeline. So our current thought is to build a custom localization factory using localeCalculator to populate a cookie or possibly a session var.